# Compare two Strings with different encoding

Tags: javascript, encoding, character-encoding, greasemonkey

I'm writing a Greasemonkey script. I need to compare two strings, where one of these is equal to `document.location.href`.

If `document.location.href` is equal to `"http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=ñáñara"` then I need to do something extra, but I can't determine if the two strings are equal, because `document.location.href` is converted to another character set. This is an example:

```
var currentLocation = document.location.href.toString();
var targetLocation = 'http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=ñáñara';

alert(currentLocation + '\n' + targetLocation);

/* OUTPUT:

    http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=%C3%B1%C3%A1%C3%B1ara
    http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=ñáñara
*/
```

How can I convert two strings to the same character set?

Comment: Don't know, but why do you use two different encodings in one page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use:

```
var url = decodeURI(window.location.href);
```

Should be enough.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI

Comment: What can be used when another string instead of a url? For example, a server retrieve the name of a document called "Ñáñara.doc", but I get like '% C3% B1% C3% A1% C3% B1ara'

Comment: You can use [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent).

Answer (score 1):

or the other way round: `encodeURI("http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=ñáñara")`

Comment: What can be used when another string instead of a url? For example, a server retrieve the name of a document called "Ñáñara.doc", but I get like '% C3% B1% C3% A1% C3% B1ara'

Comment: the same function of course.
Because obviously, the encodeURI function is used to generate the string '% C3% B1% C3% A1% C3% B1ara'